# Does GR gravity obey a form of Gauss' law?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gauss-law

In Newtonian mechanics, [Gauss' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity) is the assertion that, for any volume $V$ enclosed within a regular surface $\partial V$, the flux of the acceleration produced by gravity through $\partial V$ is exactly $-4 \pi G M(V)$, with $G$ the gravitational constant and $M(V)$ the amount of grave mass contained in the volume $V$.

**Question** What changes, if we replace the Newtonian gravitational field with a relativistic one? That is, if instead of Poisson's equation it obeys Einstein's field equation?

Consider a test particle that is an ideal accelerometer embedded in the inertial navigation system (INS) of a spaceship: a known proof mass $\mu$ forced to rest w/resp to a perfectly rigid frame, by applying Lorentz forces that are constantly measured with perfect accuracy.
If the rigid frame is at rest at a given position in a Newtonian stationary field, the INS measures the negated weight of the proof mass at this position. Suppose this measure is carried out at every point on the boundary of the volume $V$, then compute the flux of the measured force:  Newton's first law plus Gauss's law imply it is, up to the constant *positive* factor $+4\pi\mu G$, the total grave mass enclosed in the volume $V$.

If $V$ is a delimited lump of vacuum aboard a rigid spaceship in free fall, this experiment will detect no grave mass (except that of the surrounding INS): this results from the Newtonian background potential having Laplacian $0$ within the spaceship. If instead, the spaceship has landed and the volume $V$ and the INS rotate at the same constant rate, say $\omega = 2 \pi$ rad per 23h 56mn, then the grave mass will include an additional $\omega^2 \over {4 \pi G}$ ~ 6.34 kg/m^3. Et caetera.

Now, switch to relativistic fields. Volume elements are defined in terms of a Riemannian metric, forces are now tangent vectors to a space-time manifold, however it is still possible to carry out the experiment described above; what is its outcome?

My guess is, a GR form of Gauss' theorem holds **if**, at every point of the boundary surface $\partial V$:

1. the test particle is at rest in absolute spacetime and comoving with $\partial V$, i. e. its space coordinates remain constant along its world line, whereas the equation of $\partial V$ is written as a condition involving only the space coordinates,
2. the energy-momentum tensor and the metric are stationary (constant along the world line of the particle) and
3. the metric at that point makes the world line time-like;

then the time component of the 4-force opposing gravity is $0$,   i. e. it reduces to a measurable, constant 3-force, and its flux through $\partial V$ is the total energy-momentum enclosed in $V$, over $4 \pi G c^2$.

I only checked it in the case of $\partial V$ a stationary coordinate sphere in a Schwarzschild vacuum, finding the flux to be independent of the axial coordinate $r$ and exactly equal to the Schwarzschild radius, including in negative space i. e. with $r < 0$.

This is the result I would expect for a vacuum solution:
in general, if the grave contents of $V$ is a stationary flow of matter with 4-velocity $ \dot{x}^\alpha$ and energy-momentum tensor $T_{\alpha \beta}$, the enclosed energy-momentum must be $ \iiint\limits_V T_{\alpha \beta} \dot{x}^\alpha \dot{x}^\beta dV$.

In the case of Kerr vacuums, things get more messy and direct computations are a bit too tedious for me, to put it politely; it will be much, much easier if a general theorem guarantees that in any given, simply connected volume at any moment in time, the enclosed mass is zero when the field is a vacuum solution.

Comment: Related: [Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Birkhoff%27s+theorem

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222502/2451